# kubernetes log management via filebeat to logstash

Tags: kubernetes, logstash, filebeat

Im in the process of migrating some services to kubernetes and Im looking into a solution for logfile management. Said services can be rather noisy (log-speaking) and as they will be in various containers I plan to centralize the logs using logstash->elasticsearch.

If these were VMs id probably setup filebeat to grab logs and set logrotate to be pretty firm about not letting any files get more than a day old. Is this the appropriate mechanism for kubernetes? I don't want to cause problems on the kube hosts by filling up disks.

In essence: Each container would have a service + filebeat + strict logrotate policy. Logs would be forwarded to a central logstash instance.

Is that reasonable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no restriction to use any kind of log aggregators. You can use  service + filebeat + strict logrotate policy if it is applicable for you. Also, as an alternative you can use [fluend-bit](https://fluentbit.io/documentation/) as a log aggregator and  than send it to ELK.

In [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/logging-elasticsearch-kibana/) you could find good how to how to use ELK + fluend.

Comment: Sounds like 'anything goes'.. got it.. ty